# Is there a way to cut idle CPU usage under Multitasking MS-DOS 4.0?

Tags: ms-dos, emulation

The operating system variously known as ‘Multitasking MS-DOS 4.0’ or ‘European MS-DOS’, to avoid confusion with the better-known single-tasking MS-DOS 4.0, has the mildly irritating flaw that it doesn’t invoke the `HLT` instruction that stops the CPU when the system is idle. This has the effect that whenever the OS is run in a virtual machine, CPU usage of the host spikes to 100%, whether the guest is actually doing anything or not, inevitably leading to my laptop CPU fan revving up with an all-too-familiar noise.

There doesn’t seem to be a simple, obvious way to remedy this. Unlike the mainstream edition of the OS, there is not [an idle interrupt](https://fd.lod.bz/rbil/interrup/dos_kernel/28.html) to which one can hook a TSR which can invoke `HLT` on its own. Having studied (what I assume to be) the kernel idle loop in a debugger, there doesn’t even seem to be any room to squeeze in a `HLT` instruction by patching the kernel. Here it is disassembled:

```
0506:3DE0 0E                PUSH    CS
0506:3DE1 1F                POP     DS
0506:3DE2 FB                STI
0506:3DE3 F6066105FF        TEST    BYTE PTR [0561],FF
0506:3DE8 74F8              JZ      3DE2
0506:3DEA E832FD            CALL    3B1F
0506:3DED EBF1              JMP     3DE0
```

Is there a way to inject a halt instruction into the idle loop somewhere?

Comment: Is it feasible (permissible?) to post the code of the idle loop? May give someone inspiration...

Comment: Just to confirm, Vernon Brooks [explicitly lists](https://sites.google.com/site/pcdosretro/multitaskingdos4) “no INT 28h or INT 2Ah function 84h idle callout”.

Comment: Can you find a more or less unused memory area somewhere else where you can patch in a loop with a HLT instruction? In that case you can jump to that loop and back.

Comment: @UncleBod That’s what I thought too. But such area is not easily found in the original kernel image, while if I were to allocate it at runtime (in some kind of TSR-like utility), I don’t know if I could assume with impunity that the idle loop is always in this segment and/or how to reliably discover it.

Comment: How do you know that it can properly recover from a HLT?

Comment: The not-retro answer: some virtual machines allow you to limit the maximum CPU time expended. E.g. in VirtualBox look for 'Execution Cap'. Or, less satisfactorily, your OS may allow you to put a limit on the virtual machine software, see e.g. [CPULimit](https://github.com/opsengine/cpulimit).

Comment: @WillHartung It's a closed loop around a memory location. The only way to flip that location is by an interrupt routine doing so (Using DMA would be way too obscure in a PC-XT environment). And each and every interrupt will after it's termination continue execution after a HLT. Exactly what the routine requires. But the test can not be simply replaced by a HLT, as it shoulc only leave the loop if an interrupt happened that changed the flag as well.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124758/discussion-on-question-by-user3840170-is-there-a-way-to-cut-idle-cpu-usage-under).

Answer (score 8):

In place and without changing other code: **No**

Simply because there is no shorter encoding of that sequence - that is unless we rely on

- additional information how (and when) the tested byte changes

and/or

- how and when values set here gets reused or not

and/or

- certain register setup prior to this routine.

---

The basic issue here is that a HLT instruction will end/continue operation after *any* arbitrary interrupt was handled, but it's not said that every interrupt will as well set the flag byte at CS:0561h. All that do not set that byte should of loop back and halt again.

---

There is always the usual method of jumping out by replacing the test instruction by a call to some new routine, intended to whatever is necessary - like

```
    HLT
    TEST xxxx
    RET
```

The 5 bytes of the TEST instruction is long enough to even hold a far call, so it can be located anywhere. This method has the advantage that all other code is untouched.

---

**Possible Other Ways** depending on code/workings outside the core loop:

Of course if it can be guaranteed that certain data is present, some instructions can be used for patching like

- if DS is already equalling CS when entered, then the PUSH/POP pair can be dropped and their space repurposed to add a HLT instruction

```
0506:3DE0 90                NOP
0506:3DE1 FB                STI
0506:3DE2 F4                HLT
0506:3DE2 F6066105FF        TEST    BYTE PTR [0561],FF
0506:3DE8 74F7              JZ      3DE1
0506:3DEA E832FD            CALL    3B1F
0506:3DED EBF1              JMP     3DE0
```

Likewise if it's guaranteed that DS is not used later on with the assumption of still having the same value as CS, they can be replaced by a segment override prefix freeing up a much needed byte for the HLT instruction.

- if DS gets reloaded afterwards (like in the function starting at CS:3B1Fh) without being uses first, the following patch might work:

```
0506:3DE0 FB                STI
0506:3DE1 F4                HLT
0506:3DE2 2EF6066105FF      TEST    CS:BYTE PTR [0561],FF
0506:3DE8 74F6              JZ      3DE0
0506:3DEA E832FD            CALL    3B1F
0506:3DED EBF1              JMP     3DE0
```

Comment: "Or"... Or what??? Now I'm going to have to go into my HLT routine waiting for the next character read from your keyboard...

Comment: @JonCuster Well, you got me ... you got me thinking again, so here's a second possible patch :))

Comment: Very nice. And now I can get back to work again!